# esc_html__ security : what for in this example?

Tags: security, wp-localize-script

how does `esc_html__` (the 2nd one) protect the `$message` variable from being hacked ? what's the point to use this protection here (the second one with a plain text)?

```
<?php

function unknown(){

    /* If the user input any text, escape it. */
    if ( !empty ( $_POST['unknown'] ) )
        $message = esc_html ( $_POST['unknown'] );

    /* If no text was input, use a default, translated message. */
    else 
        $message = esc_html__( 'No message input by the user.', 'unknown' );

    return $message;
}

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really doesn't do much in that scenario. If you're going to leave that message as a string constant instead of something that is system or user generated, you're fine using one of the other translation functions: `__()` or `_x()`. `esc_html__()` is a little overkill for that particular line of code.

**Edit:**

The main reason for the `esc_` functions is to protect your site against bad input, either intentional or accidental. You're going to want to use the [appropriate function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) whenever you're working with any data that can be manipulated by a user or is not explicitly set by you.

If you have any questions about WP functions in the future my recommendation would be to check the source. Either do a search in a WP install to find the function, or click the link at the bottom of the codex page that links to the source file.

Comment: thanks, so it is `useless` here? i found it in a book, but i guess the "esc_" function is to be used when a "user" is writing something, right? or is it because a "hacker" can intercept the communication between the code and the file with all the translations...? i don't really know about this...

Comment: Updated my answer to be a bit more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

One major principle of preventing security holes is "Escape late." That means that, ideally, `esc_html()` or `esc_attr()` should be used right when you echo or return the final HTML, not before. So, that's one thing that the example you gave gets wrong.

As for the purpose of `esc_html__()`, as I understand it, is to prevent weird characters from translated strings (not the original ones you see in the code) from messing up textareas and such.